# Is there a board-to-wire header that accepts a female JST SM 3-pin connectors?

Tags: connector

I've looked everywhere on Digikey and Mouser and can not find a compatible board-to-wire header that can accept a [JST type SM 3-pin 2.5mm](https://www.adafruit.com/product/1663) female that looks like this. ...

[image]

Are these connectors available?

These connectors are commonly used for WS2812B RGB LED strings.

Comment: As the datasheet says, JST's SM range are all wire-to-wire. Probably easier to make up a board-to-wire adapter fly lead using a connector of your choice at the board end.

Comment: The existing incoming wires are sized to reach the would-be connector, so the fly leads would add extra length and bulk so I would like to find a way to avoid them. Also always nice to avoid needing an extra custom part. But definitely a fall back. Thanks!

Comment: Look at chinese suppliers, or get one manufactured from a cable manufacturer.

Answer (score 1):

While looking at various JST connectors, I discovered that the JST [NH series](https://www.jst-mfg.com/product/detail_e.php?series=182) wire-to-board connector uses the same female contacts as the SM series, and is the same 2.5mm pitch. So while the NH header will not provide locking or orientation keying with the SM connector, it should fit well.

With that said, I've also had no trouble plugging SM connectors onto plain old 2.54mm headers.

FWIW, I, too, wish JST had a series of connectors that included wire-to-board, wire-to-wire, and perhaps even board-to-board as well.

Comment: I would imagine that 2.5mm into 2.54 may or may not work depending on the number of pins. 2.5mm is a weird pitch. If you have the option to pick something else then go with either 2.0mm or 2.54mm (0.1 inch). These are both super standardized pitches and you'll have lots more options and second source.